# Ubuntu 11.10 GNOME shell stuck in fallback mode

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I installed ubuntu 11.10, gnome shell is stuck in fallback mode (not able to change to fallback mode off from 'System Settings'. Choose 'System Information' then 'Graphics'), I think it can be a video drivers issue.
Thinkpad t400 
after a fresh install monitor shows "unknown"

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In fallback mode your gnome shell will work in 2D settings. Thus all you need is setting your session type while your logging in to "gnome" or "3D".
If you have "gnome-session-fallback" installed on your ubuntu, you can use this facility to fallback.
In you log in page while you want choose user and authenticate, you can change your desktop session to gnome 2D or gnome(3D).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am logging in into gnome (3D) but when I am in it looks like gnome 2D. Not sure why, first time I installed gnome shell it work smooth, after a fresh ubuntu 11.10 install I can't make gnome work.
Thanks!

Comment: If you have got your answer truly, please mark the answer an accepted and answered. Thanks.